# Is there a way to get public pair final/non-final rejection documents in textual form?

Tags: pair, documents, prosecution

I'm looking for easiest way to get textual information from public pair documents, examiner rejection documents to be specific. All the patent prosecution documents it seams are in pdf-image format. Getting text from that requires OCR, which is tedious.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The documents are submitted by the applicants in writing or pdf. Getting text from them requires OCR, there's no way around that.

Comment: Corrected question. I need final/non-final rejection documents. But I guess it's the same story here even if USPTO examiner submits the document.

Comment: @alex I think so. If it's not in pdf-text in pair, you won't get it anywhere else, after all, PAIR is the original source for every other database.